# How can you hide/remove the Movement/Aim Indicator?

Tags: pc, fifa-18

I'm struggling to find the option that removes the movement/aim indicator in Fifa 18, I've tried to disable *Analog Sprint* and *FIFA Trainer*, but I just can't seem to get rid of the movement arrow.

The image below shows the movement/aim indicator.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it yesterday and this worked for me:

If you toggle the trainer, the arrow should be toggled as well. Or you can toggle the arrow separately:

1. Pause a running game, go to *Trainer* settings
2. Set up the trainer...
   a) **Status** toggles between show/hide (like pressing the right stick)
   b) **Mode** lets you select what the Trainer shows (the arrow, direction, options, etc)
   c) The other Settings become available when you choose to enable them:

   - Buttons Mode (Trainer level auto/manual, if enabled under *b)*)
   - Level (if mode is set to manual)
   - Mechanics (if enabled under *b)*):

     - Pass receiver (circle under the pass recipient)
     - Shot Elevation (arrow indicating the strength of a shot)

[image]

So the short answer is: Change the Mode to select what you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

On a 360 pad, you just have to press the right joystick.